# Nexted list iterating using jinja2 flask

Tags: python, list, dictionary, flask, jinja2

I have 3list coming from flask contain the "name" "department" "position", I need to create a table and pollute the rows using all 3list...

**problem I can't able to access all 3list data at once

so I read in somewhere in StackOverflow to link my list into dictionary and dictionary to the list

```
an_item = dict(name=names, department= departments, position=positions)
itema.append(an_item)
```

** it works fine if the name is string, not a list

FLASK SIDE:

```
names = ["Alice", "Mike", ...]
department = ["CS", "MATHS", ... ]
position = ["HEAD", "CR", ....]

an_item = dict(name=names, department= departments, position=positions)
itema.append(an_item)
```

HTML:

```
<tbody>

   {% for item in items %}
   <tr>
       <td>{{item.name}}</td> #printing the list ["alice", "mike", ...]
       <td>{{item.department}}</td>
       <td>{{item.position}}</td>
   </tr>
   {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

I want a simple table for name department and position

```
Name  Department Position
Alice CS         Head
Mike  MATHS      CR
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are building your dictionary incorrectly. When you do `dict(name=names, department= departments, position=positions)`, this is actually just creating a key of names with a value of the list of names, and a key of department with a list of departments. This means `item.name` is actually a list of all the names.

What I imagine you want is a list of dictionaries for each name-department-position. The way to do this is to loop through the your parallel lists then create a dictionary for each index and append to your list.

```
names = ['joe', 'alice', 'bill']
departments = ['CS', 'Math', 'Eng']
position = ['HEAD', 'CR', 'PROF']

items = []
for i in range(len(names)):
    item = dict(name=name[i], department=departments[i], position=positions[i])
    items.append(item)

print(items) # [{'name': 'joe', 'deparment': 'CS', 'position': 'HEAD}, {'name': 'alice', 'department': 'Math',...}...]
```

Then in your HTML, you will want to use bracket operators or `.get()`

```
<tbody>

   {% for item in items %}
   <tr>
       <td>{{item['name']}}</td>
       <td>{{item['department']}}</td>
       <td>{{item['position']}}</td>
   </tr>
   {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

This should give you the table you are looking for.

Comment: Okay so its kinda become the tuple, I happened to know when searching for the answer that there is a function called zip which kinda does the same with loops... I imagine jsonify would also be a good option, what do you think?

Comment: No tuples here. `items` is a list of a dictionaries, each dictionary represents a row in the table. `jsonify` would be better used when making api endpoints that return json. In this situation you are building server-side templates, a list of dictionaries as I did above is likely your best choice.